# Hera (5.1) - MacBook; Installation failed at grub install

Tags: release-hera, grub, macbook

I have a late 2006 MacBook (MacBook2,1).
I downloaded Elementary OS (5.1, Hera) and plunked it on a USB stick.
I tried in in "live mode" and all was good.
I committed to installing eOS and it was nearly done but died with this error:

```
Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda
Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed.
This is a fatal error.
```

I clicked "OK" and got this:
    Installer crashed
    (stuff about auto-filing a bug report)

I clicked "CLOSE"
I then got a dialog saying that the installer encountered an "... unrecoverable error" and a desktop session will start so that I may investigate the problem.
I clicked "OK" and got a desktop.

When I reboot the machine, I am now presented a grub prompt.

I web searched and web searched and found https://bit.ly/2XcO2Ii and https://bit.ly/3dhpJ1t  Both these sites are ostensibly the same.

I followed the magic spell given: I proceed with a "manual boot," i.e.

- I located (hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
- set root=(hd0,gpt2)
- Got the UUID of the partition
- Ran linux /boot/vmlinuz...
- Ran initrd /boot/initrd...
- Ran boot

The system came up.

Moving on to fixing the EFI partition ...

I ran sudo add-apt-repository ppa:detly/mactel-utils

It failed; turns out I needed to first install "software-properties-common" first ... I did so.

Re-ran sudo add-apt-repository ppa:detly/mactel-utils and got this error:

```
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/detly/mactel-utils/ubuntu bionic Release
    404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/detly/mactel-utils/bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I'm now dead in the water. Since I can't install mactel-boot et al. (as per the web page), this whole endeavor is a failure at this point. I'm at a loss as to what to do next.

I've searched SE for solutions but may are outdated, reference Windows/dual booting, or are straight-up contradictory, e.g. same thread: "The solution is to boot to USB and NOT UEFI" v. "You need to install from the UEFI partition on your eOS USB stick"

For the record, I am *NOT* interested in dual booting.
I do *NOT* care about preserving the HD's previous content or structure.
All I want is a fresh, clean eOS install.

Answer (score 0):

Macbook2,1 has 32bit EFI.

Normal grub tries to install 64bit efi loader, so

You need to Install grub-efi-ia32 and run grub-install.

Here I have a bookmark which describes the whole installation process on Macbook2,1.
https://cloud-infra.engineer/installing-elementary-os-on-my-late-2006-macbook/